# LINQ pivot in joined tables

Tags: c#, linq

```
-------------           
Products    |
-------------       
id          |
name        |
price       |
image       |
-------------

-------------
Sizes       |
-------------   
id          |
name        |
quantity    |
id_product  |
-------------
```

in table `Sizes` I'm keeping different sizes and quantity in each sizes of my product. For example I have a pair of jeans in my products, but in table `Sizes` I'm keeping them in Sizes.Name M and quantity 20, Sizes.Name XL and quantity 30, etc.

In my project when I want to display all the data im gridview Im having sth like this

```
id      |name       |price | size_name      | quantity  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
1       jeans       100     M                   20
1       jeans       100     XL                  30
1       jeans       100     S                   45
```

etc.

what I want to display is:

```
id      |name       |price | S  | M  | XL |
-------------------------------------------------
1       jeans       1000    45    20   30
```

So I read that I have to use a pivot but don't know how to start and what to do next. Here's some of my code:

```
var query = from product in context.Products
            join size in context.Sizes on product.ID equals r.Product.ID    
            //what's the next step?    
            select new {  };

dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

> ===================================
>
> EDIT
>
> ====================================

now i have sth like this

well `{id, name}` is not a key,
but there's seems to be another problem,

```
var q = (from p in context.Produkty
                     join r in context.Rozmiary
                         on p.ID equals r.Produkt.ID
                         into sizes
                     select new
                     {
                         S = sizes.Where(x => x.Nazwa == NazwaRozmiaru.S).Sum() ?? 0
                     });
           dataGridView1.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

gives me this

```
Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Magazynier.Model.Rozmiary>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Sum(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<decimal?>)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Piotr\Downloads\Magazynier (7)\Magazynier\Magazynier\Form1.cs  45  34  Magazynier
```

and this

```
Error   3   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Magazynier.Model.Rozmiary>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<decimal?>' C:\Users\Piotr\Downloads\Magazynier (7)\Magazynier\Magazynier\Form1.cs  45  34  Magazynier
```

and this

```
Error   4   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.    C:\Users\Piotr\Downloads\Magazynier (7)\Magazynier\Magazynier\Form1.cs  47  43  Magazynier
```

and my Sizes (aka Rozmiary) looks like this in c#

```
public enum NazwaRozmiaru
{
    S,
    M,
    L,
}

public class Rozmiary : KlasaBazowa
{
    public Produkty Produkt { get; set; }

    public NazwaRozmiaru Nazwa { get; set; }

    public int Ilosc { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

- `{id, name}` is a key for Sizes
- You only want to display S, M, and XL sizes.

Try this:

```
from product in context.Products
join size in context.Sizes
    on product.ID equals r.Product.ID
    into sizes
select new {
    product.id,
    product.name,
    product.price,
    S = sizes.Where(x => x.name == "S").Select(x => x.quantity).SingleOrDefault(),
    M = sizes.Where(x => x.name == "M").Select(x => x.quantity).SingleOrDefault(),
    XL = sizes.Where(x => x.name == "XL").Select(x => x.quantity).SingleOrDefault()
}
```

If `{id, name}` is not a key, then plug this in:

```
 S = sizes.Where(x => x.name == "S").Sum(x => x.quantity) ?? 0
```

If you want to display all sizes, but you don't know what sizes there will be, you won't be able to get a nice table using LINQ, but you can do this:

```
select new {
    product.id,
    product.name,
    product.price,
    quantitiesBySize = sizes.ToDictionary(size => size.name, size => size.quantity)
}
```

Comment: Upvoted the answer. Small typo: x.name == "S" even for M and XL sizes.